# Using fb:// To Share a Post through the Facebook App with Web Interface

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

One of my sites has a custom share plugin that I've written and I would like to try to get the 'sharing' feature to open up in the native Facebook app if possible. I know that you can use `fb://` to open up the app but from what I've read, this is part of FBML which has been deprecated for several years. What I ideally would like is to have the link open up the FB app with a pre-populated link in the share box that the user could then just automatically share. Basically the functionality of the sharer.php script (it's ok if it pulls the data from the OG tags).

I know it can be done in iOS apps (and probably Android) but is it possible to do through a web interface?

I have the links I'm using only showing on mobile devices through some Javascript so I wouldn't have to worry about it causing any problems sitewide.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Facebook doesn't officially support any url schema so even if you are able to figure out the URL to use, there is no guarantee that this won't break in the future, native App can change with no notice. If you use the javascript plugin you'll have a nice experience although it will open in a web browser. In general, if you do not find information in developers.facebook.com about what you're trying to do, it's because it's not supported and therefore, there will be no guarantee that it will work. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: I don't understand why facebook doesn't have this feature. A lot of people browse the internet through their phones and nobody is logged into facebook on their mobile browser. Surely everyone is crying out for this feature?

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = encodeURIComponent('http://example.org/');
window.open(
    'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+url,
    'Share on Facebook',
    'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600'
);
```

That's the simplest way I do it ;)

Comment: This isn't what I'm talking about. I'm talking about opening the FB app. It was explained in the question that I want the functionality of the sharer.php link but in the FB app.